# Controlar o evendo do botão voltar do navegador

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou utilizando a ***função*** em `jQuery onbeforeunload` mas ela está sendo ativada pelo voltar do navegador (Back Button).

Gostaria de saber como controlar o evento voltar do navegador, já tentei várias possíveis soluções mas nenhuma funcionou.

Meu objetivo é anular a ação do `onbeforeunload` quando o botão voltar do navegador for ativado, para que a mensagem não apareça.

```
var botao_voltar == MANEIRA DE CAPTURAR O EVENTO;

if (botao_voltar == false)
{
    onbeforeunload = function()
    {
        return 'MENSAGEM PARA O USUÁRIO';
    }
}
```

Comment: `window.history.back();` ?

Comment: Podes explicar a funcionalidade que queres ter usando o `onbeforeunload `? vai ser difícil separar esses eventos.

Comment: @Sergio fiz um exemplo do Script, na verdade eu quero anular o botão voltar do onbeforeunload

Answer (score 3):

Vou dar uma solução que tambem envolve alguns outros problemas que venho sofrido com meu cliente e, que muita gente tem dito que eh impossível contornar.

Bom, segue o código comentado, onde ele permite apenas que a **mensagem de saída** da pagina seja exibida  quando ocorre o click no botão reload, ou quando o cliente vai para uma **nova pagina**. Por exemplo **digitando um novo endereco na barra de URL**..

MAS, se ele apertar **F5**, ou **CTRL+R**, ou **BackSpace**, ou ainda dar **click no botão Back** do navegador ele executa aquela ação, mas **não exibe a mensagem de alerta de saída da pagina**.

no caso na nossa empresa, ele atende:

```
       // para o botao voltar do navegador

    detectedBrowser= Qual_Eh_o_Seu_Browser?;

            if(detectedBrowser==InternetExplorer){history.pushState( "nohb", null, "URL_Corretaaaaa" );}
            else    {history.pushState( "nohb", null, "" );}

            window.onpopstate = function(event) {               // JS version
        //  $(window).on( "popstate", function(event){          // Jquery version
                console.log('MESSAGE  213 = ' + flag_beforeunload ) 
                if( !event.state ){                             // JS version
        //      if( !event.originalEvent.state ){               // Jquery version

                        // para desabilitar o botao BACK do navegador, descomente as linhas abaixo:
                        //  history.pushState( "nohb", null, "" );
                        //  return;

                        // para tratar o evento UnBeforeUnload voce tem as linhas abaixo..  modifique conforme sua necessidade... neste exemplo ele so volta uam pagina, sem pop up.
                            flag_beforeunload=false;
                         window.history.back();


                }
            };


//
//escutando o teclado
//

    document.onkeydown = KeyCheck;
    function KeyCheck(e) {
        var key = (window.event) ? event.keyCode : e.keyCode;
        if(key==116) {flag_beforeunload=false;}     
        if(key==8) {flag_beforeunload=false;}       
        if (e.keyCode == 82 && e.ctrlKey) {flag_beforeunload=false;}        
        if(e.keyCode == 91) {flag_beforeunload=false;}      // safari
        if (e.keyCode == 82) {flag_beforeunload=false;}     // safari

        document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = "key = "+key + " - " + flag_beforeunload;
    }



//
// o evento UnBeforeUnload
//
        window.onbeforeunload = function(e){
            var msg = 'Deseja mesmo sair?';
            e = e || window.event;

            if(e)
                if (flag_beforeunload == true) {
                    return msg;
                }
        }
```

Por favor use com cuidado, lembre-se que eh um exemplo.... 
então esta longe de ser perfeito!! deve ser adequado as suas necessidades
obrigado!

Ele funciona bem no chrome, Jah no firefox, iexplorer e safari ainda estou vendo maneiras de funcionar.

ps: tambem coloquei no [fidle, mas nesta pagina](https://jsfiddle.net/seniDEac/bxptkbeq/3/) não esta funcionando completamente.. por favor faca local para testes...